# how to http sample reuse in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

When using jmeter for interface testing, I want to reuse a certain httpsample. For example, there are 3 http requests, the first http request needs to be sent before the third http request is sent, which is equivalent to initialization, but I don’t want to add an http sampler before the third http request, which will cause http requests Redundant and difficult to maintain. what should I do? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your "fist http request" under the [Test Fragment](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Fragment)
2. Reference it where required using the [Module Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Module_Controller)

This way you can [avoid code duplication](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) and have only one instance of the "first" http request sampler across your test plan

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works. Is it possible to use only one module controller? It would be more simpler.